# Lavacharts display 2 Piecharts, second chart has no data

Tags: laravel, charts

I am trying to display 2 piechart in same view, this is my view code :

```
<div class="panel-body form-horizontal">
    {{-- <div id="morris-donut-chart"></div> --}}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div id="chart-div"></div>
        @piechart('tgt','chart-div')
      </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div id="chart-div2"></div>
        @piechart('capai','chart-div2')
      </div>

  </div>
```

both success display, but the second chart has no data.

[Piechart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX4U7.png)

i think the variable of data table is not problem , when i use dd(), it's has data.

[Data of Capai](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1Cdo.png)

my controller code :

```
public function statistik()
{
    $lava = new Lavacharts;

    $ket = array("totalTarget" => 0, "totalCapai" => 0);

    $target_ = Target::select('grup')
            ->selectRaw("SUM(nilai) AS jumlah")
            ->groupBy('grup')
            ->get()
            ->toArray();

    $data = \Lava::DataTable();
    $data->addStringColumn('Target')
              ->addNumberColumn('Percent');

    foreach($target_ as $row){
        $data->addRow([$row['grup'], $row['jumlah'] ]);
        $ket["totalTarget"] += $row['jumlah'];
    }
    \Lava::PieChart('tgt', $data, [
                'title' => 'Target :',
                'height' => '300',
                'is3D'   => true,
            ]);

    $capai_ = Faktur::select('nama')
                ->selectRaw('SUM(qty) AS jumlah')
                ->groupBy('sub_group')
                ->get()
                ->toArray();

    $data_capai = \Lava::DataTable();
    $data_capai->addStringColumn('Pencapaian')
                ->addNumberColumn('Percent');

    foreach($capai_ as $row_){
        $data_capai->addRow([$row_['nama'], $row_['jumlah'] ]);
        $ket["totalCapai"] += $row_['jumlah'];
    }

    // dd($data_capai);
    \Lava::PieChart('capai', $data_capai, [
                'title' => 'Pencapaian :',
                'height' => '300',
                'is3D'   => true,
            ]);

    return view('dashboard', compact('lava', 'ket'));
}
```

Is there something I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already fixed it.

All I need is to convert data to Float.